# Have I contradicted the "law" non-contradiction?

Tags: metaphysics, empiricism, constructivism

In the 2nd half of the 20th century the American mathematician Haskell Curry and logician William Alvin Howard discovered an analogy between logical proofs and working computer programs. This is known as the Curry-Howard correspondence.
Mathematical proofs are working computer programs. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curry%E2%80%93Howard_correspondence

Computers are physical entities obeying the laws of physics, so if there exists any object in the PHYSICAL UNIVERSE which behaves contrary to the Law of Non-Contradiction (LNC) we have living proof that the LNC is a false authority.

Therefore all I need to do to render the LNC meaningless is to present a computer program which *EVALUATES* ( ( A = A ) and (A != A) ) to  True without producing an error.

Like this: https://repl.it/repls/UrbanUniquePixels

I have invented an object in space-time which behaves exactly contrary to what the LNC prescribes.

So if contradictions can and do exist physical form, but logic prescribes that they don't then surely you need to go with empiricism on this one and 
discard the LNC?

Is this sufficient proof that the LNC is a meaningless "law"?
A false authority!

EDIT (after some feedback): This is NOT a quantum effect. By implementing it on a classical computer I am manifesting this duality in the classical realm.

Comment: The issue is already discussed; see e.g. the [particle-wave duality of QM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality) : does it mean that we have to leave Non Contradiction ? Maybe... it is still an open issue. See also [Quantum Logic](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/qt-quantlog/).

Comment: See also [Dialetheism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/dialetheism/).

Comment: OK. Perhaps worth nothing. This is NOT a quantum effect.

By implementing it on a classical computer - I am manifesting the phenomenon, empirically in the classical realm.

It is from the Dialethism page that I got this idea last night.

Comment: And see also [Quine' Holism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confirmation_holism) : if our "received" scientific worldview is contradicted by facts, we have to modify **some** theories on which the said worldview is based. There are "layers" of theories and the mathematical and logical ones lays at the deeper level: but, if necessary, we have to consider to modify also them.

Comment: Proofs are working Turing Machine programs.  Turing Machines don't exist in the physical world, they exist in a 'mathematical' world.  As noted, the Law of Non-contradiction is a mathematical axiom, and does not apply to the physical world either.  But it applies to the mathematical world, which contains all the things we can efficiently communicate.  Just take the short cut and accept the implications of Curry's paradox, Berry's paradox or Russel's paradox.  The mathematical world is very convenient, but it is not only not realistic, it is internally flawed.

Comment: There is an analogy between logical proofs and working computer programs. Computers are physical entities obeying the laws of physics. Therefore, if there exists an object which behaves contrary to the Law of Non-Contradiction we have living proof that the LNC is a false authority. This argument is fallacious. First, analogy is not a logical connection. Second, computers are physical, but computer programs are not, they are abstractions. And third, logic is grammar used to express and test physical laws, it makes no sense to say that an object behaves according or contrary to a logical law.

Comment: the LNC is a "false authority" in your program, but that just doesn't mean that any of the laws of physics are behaving contrary to it. i don't see how it's different to the observation that many people often fail to conform to it in their thinking

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Psychology_of_reasoning

Comment: @confused https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_crisis#In_psychology

I am an applied scientist. I know how to avoid fooling myself better than most physicists. 

I know the inside of my mind better than any psychologist.


Know thyself and all that.

Comment: cool @TypeTheorist but all i meant to do was back up my claim that many people violate the LNC. or you would say they merely seem to? i just don't see the difference between your computer program and a series of sentences or propositions that do likewise

Comment: @Conifold computer programs are not abstract. The Language in which you write computer programs is abstract.

Compilers/interpreters convert this language into bytecode which has an actual, direct effect on the CPU's behaviour. Which is as physical an effect as this gets.

Comment: jobermark@ Turing machines exist. Computers, Your mind.

These are FINITE turing machines because physical universe with finite resources.
And so we have Type 1 chomsky grammars: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Context-sensitive_grammar

But other than the difference of "infinite memory and time" they are identical. So for all practical purposes Curry-Howard applies to computers in this universe.

Comment: my verbalizing a bad argument (i do this a lot) likewise has a real physical effect in the world? i don't follow why it being an instance of code rather than speech makes any difference @TypeTheorist i guess the idea is that the computer is actually *behaving* in that way: but so is my discourse. it's not like the physical make-up of the computer is violating LNC: just like my body isn't

Comment: A computer can't verbalize a "bad argument.". If the code runs it has conequences.
Energy is being used. Work is being done. Matter (memory) is being altered.

Real. Measurable consequences.  If you want to call those consequences "contradictions" - fine.

But they are real, empirical phenomena.

I made the LNC produce consequences. 

The opposite consequences it prescribes.

This demonstrates that I am in control of a "law", I can tell a "law" what to do...

Comment: You have to take the computer programs as abstract if you want the Curry-Howard correspondence to make sense. If you mean C++ code executed on a PC, with lights blinking, your analogy does not work. Ink on paper is a physical thing too, but asking if physical things obey English grammar still makes no sense.

Comment: Conifold@ Ink on paper is not provably Turing-complete.
My computer is.

Computers are now the de-facto, objective standards for validity. Automated theorem proving and all...

Any system that is provably Turing-complete is Lambda-calculus equivalent. 
Cury-Howard applies.

Whether I write the proof-of-concept in Python or C++ is irrelevant. There exists some lambda function to translate C++ to Python. and vice versa.

This is guaranteed by Turing-equivalence.

Comment: i'm not saying that @TypeTheorist anyway hope my answer is clear enough

Comment: confused@ Sorry. Ler me try to explain this a little better.

When you say "apple" - there is nobody on the other side to interpret that utterance.
It is descriptive about the past, not prescriptive about the future.

When I write code it is prescriptive about the future. The computer is on the other end to interpret every command. Consistently.

Computer software solves the symbol-grounding problem. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbol_grounding_problem

A computer program evolves in space-time AFTER i have done "uttering it". It is a living thing.

Comment: even if you don't know what i mean when i say "apples are not apples" i do (these apples are not as tasty as i remember)... how have you shown that what is actually going on, physically, rather than in some computational "space", violates the LNC?

Comment: Your computer is full of glitches, and is not provably anything. Unless you mean an abstraction. You can not have it both ways. As Einstein said, "*As far as the laws of mathematics refer to reality, they are not certain; and as far as they are certain they do not refer to reality*".

Comment: @TypeTheorist Your program that proves a contradiction can only be said to be a "computer program" in the sense meant by the Curry-Howard correspondence if you can actually *use* the isomorphism to translate your program into a mathematical proof. Thus if you have a true "computer program" that evaluates (A = A & A != A) to True, you should be able to use C-H and translate that into an actual logical proof. Please do so.

Comment: @Bridgeburners By asking me for a logical proof you are in effect rejecting C-H. 
It computes! It is proof!

So now you don't trust the computer and want to check the work yourself. which is absolutely admirable and expected, but you are mistaking the complex for the simple.

You are not the first person who asked me to translate this into a logical proof.
And I tried. I stopped when the 30 lines of Python, became 300 lines of C++ and 14000 lines of Assembly code. If you want to unpack it further. You are welcome to. 

https://termbin.com/u9afo

Comment: I'm not up on python, but you appear to be changing the expressions defining LNC_EVALUATION and LNC_VIOLATION.  Buy adding the parentheses in the expression for LNC_VIOLATION you are changing the order precedence. If I edit your program to remove the parentheses then hit run, it returns FALSE, FALSE.

Comment: @Conifold well, i don't know how many "glitches" my computer is full of.

It can perform millions of Boolean operations without making errors. I am not that smart, diligent or rigorous. 

Einstein came before Curry-Howard. The paradigm of Mathematics is moving away from set theory and to Type theory.

This is why. We life in a finite, computational universe. You can try to fit Mathematics to reality, or reality to mathematics...

Comment: @confused I can contradict the law of identity too. It's easier actually.

Comment: @NickR that doesn't matter. What matters is the LNC is stated as a  "timeless" phenomenon, but it has three boolean operators in it.

So any machine (your brain - your computer) needs to perform three instructions to evaluate it. This is not free - it requires work/energy, but the LNC is timeless.

So you are spending non-zero energy in zero-time. Last time I checked division by zero is bad.

We live in a temporal universe. Anything that is defined as "timeless" is already a conceptual error.

Comment: @NickR define the LNC any way you want and in any way that you deem "correct". I can produce an object A which makes it return True, where the LNC prescribes False. It's just a timing attack.

Comment: @Bridgeburners furthermore you are making a fundamental error.

If I were to show you a physics experiment that demonstrates 1+1=3, but mathematics says 1+1=2.

Are you going to try fix physics or mathematics?

You are trying to make reality fit Mathematics, not Mathematics fit reality...

Comment: Yes you can fit, but there is a subtlety. You have to put logic in place first to do the fitting, since it amounts to deriving logical consequences of your physical postulates and testing them. Unlike the physical laws expressed in mathematical theories, logic plays the role of grammar. So, while it makes sense to ask if *they* fit the reality (given the logic), it does not make sense to ask if the logic does. That oil drops put together violate the laws of arithmetic does not falsify arithmetic, so CH correspondence can not give you what you want even if it worked the way you want.

Comment: @Conifold the grammar is consistent. All programming languages are regular languages.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language

What you are hinting at is "there must be a bug".  Yeah! Either there is something really weird going on, or I am right. But I can't find my mistake alone ;)

If two oil drops result in one (1+1 = 1) you have modeled the phenomenon incorrectly. Count liquid volume - not droplet quantity.

Comment: @Conifold the great property of Turing-completeness is that you are guaranteed equivalence. There is always 
SOME mechanism for translating one program into another automatically (even if the mechanism is not presently known). My 30 lines of python translates into its 14000 line assembly equivalent. And I certainly didn't do it by hand... There are tools for that.

Comment: I would dispute that your program evaluates a contradiction as true. It uses a side effect to change the internal state of the Human object when the NE function is evaluated. Try writing your program in a pure functional way: I doubt you will be able to get the desired effect.

Comment: @Bumble so ? The "Human" object is input to the LNC. 

By de-coupling the eq and ne operators it allows me to make A behave like a quantum object on a classical computer. If I use a functional language I can't do that. 

I WANT to do that. I am hacking the LNC.

Validate your inputs!

Comment: No, I am not hinting at a bug. Let's say it all goes through. All you would have shown is that programs do not model classical logic under the Curry-Howard analogy. So what? The whole theory of Turing completeness is based on classical mathematics with classical logic built in. 1+1=1 only means that arithmetic was misapplied to oil drops, but we do have a working mathematical theory of oil drops, which is based on that same arithmetic. Reality does not prescribe that logic must be applied to computers via CH, any more than math prescribes that waves must propagate in a medium like ether.

Comment: @Conifold doesn't matter Emulation. I can model a quantum computer on a classical one. It's slow as hell. But I can. Turing equivalence.

This (intuitively) tells me that quantum computers are turing-complete also. Jury is out till we find a new class of problem that only quantum can tackle.

Comment: Exactly, emulation. There is a well-known analogy between diffusion of heat and fluids, they are both described by the heat equation, so one emulates the other. That you later discover that heat is not a fluid does not mean you falsified the diffusion laws. Indeed, that emulation fails in some way does not mean *anything at all* about what it emulates. Your question mistakes emulation (of logic by programs) for the thing itself (logic).

Comment: "The thing itself" is a rather ontological concept.
I find myself heavily drawn towards behaviourism in this universe.

System dynamics/interactions/behaviours

Comment: Your program does not evaluate a contradiction. Your implementation of A != A simply returns the internal state of a Human and negates this value as a side effect. Evaluating A != A on its own will return true and then false alternately, while evaluating A == A resets the internal state to true. Since each evaluation of A != A comes immediately after an evaluation of A == A both will evaluate to true, and so the conjunction evaluates to true and its negation to false.

Comment: @Bumble you are trying your hardest to maintain the LNC!

You are trying your hardest to maintain consistency, while I am trying my hardest to maintain para-consistency, or even inconsistency  This is not a question of logic, this is a question of value. I WANT to be para-consistent and I am succeeding!

Surely as a scientist you should do everything to DISPROVE yourself, rather than confirm what you already know?

Comment: @Bumble Yes. It negates the value as a side-effect because Uncertainty principle! All of this is intentional. This is precisely how it works. And this is precisely my point. The LNC requires 3 Boolean evaluations. The LNC is also stated as a "timeless" phenomenon. SO how do you do 3 boolean operations (WORK!) in zero time? In this universe you can't. So as long as the LNC cannot be evaluated in zero-time and as long as I know how the LNC is being evaluated I CAN give it a quantum object such that I have control of the output. This is how input validation/timing attacks work.

Comment: Humans think para-consistently NOT consistently. 
We brush minor contradictions under the carpet all the time so as to maintain our language.
To invent a logic (language!) that is consistent, and then to give it to entities that are inconsistent.... you are paralyzing your thought!

Comment: @Bumble I am going to state as clearly as I can. How DO you evaluate a contradiction? We can turn this into a game-theoretic exercise. 

You can be the LNC (evaluation function) and I can be the quantum universe.

If you tell me how YOU valuate the LNC, I will give you a quantum object that breaks your evaluation. Deal?

Comment: Your second program is completely different from your first, but is equally nonsensical. You have simply redefined the equality and inequality functions to be something entirely different from their ordinary meanings. When I speak of identity, I have in mind Butler's characterisation of it: everything is what it is and not another thing. The fact that your new program evaluates A == A to false shows you are not using any recognisable notion of identity. As to equality being different from identity, I agree, but this can be handled in modern logic by distinguishing extension and intension.

Comment: @Bumble  No. You are conflating IDENTITY with EQUALITY.

A thing is IDENTICAL with itself. There is no law which says a thing needs to be EQUAL to itself.

If you can draw a distinction between the two - there is no problem.

https://repl.it/repls/GraveMeagerSet

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90438/discussion-on-question-by-type-theorist-have-i-contradicted-the-law-non-contra).

Comment: @TypeTheorist Fair enough. To complete your proof that A=A & A != A you need to show that what you wrote is, indeed, a computer program in the Curry Howard sense. Find a formal proof system such that every element of that system translates one-to-one to every operation that you performed (and that you didn't simply re-define anything to contrive your answer).

Comment: @TypeTheorist If you showed a physics experiment that demonstrates that 1+1=3 then you simply presented a system in which what you consider "addition" is not what is meant under the Peano axioms. There are already systems that are like that. If you think this requires "changing math", then you simply misunderstand the meaning of math.

Comment: @Bridgeburners I can't do that in Boolean logic. != is defined as the inversion of =. 

So = is one operation, but != is two.

In terms of work (energy used) done != is more expensive than =

Comment: @Bridgeburners The Peano axioms take integers for granted.

No mathematician can prove to me that 0.999999999999....... !=  1
For precision values from 0 to infinity.

Comment: Computer scientists and programmers  learn Specifically MATHEMATICAL LOGIC which was invented and accepted  as a distinct topic in the mid 19 century.  You did not study Aristotelian logic most likely.  If you did you would understand concepts properly.  The LNC is NOT to be read as a robot.  It is not a literal sentence to be read letter for letter especially not in Mathematical notation. Had you understood what propositions are this would not be an issue.  What the LNC expresses not what you try to make I to math is that no one can be outside of an objective truth. That alone is a concept.

Comment: I would say most people dont define objective truth correctly which is why you did not mention it. This is where math & philosophy differ in so called LOGIC. A proposition is either true or false OBJECTIVELY-- not through sense verification as in science. This is why your reasoning fails. The LNC expresses that proposition x has exactly ONE truth value in a given context at the a time.That is if someone like you claims x is both true and false at the same time there is a distinction in the context of how x is defined. X cannot be true and false at the same time, location and the same context.

Comment: @Logikal This one is true Conceptually, Mathematically and Empirically.
Do you have a definition of "objective truth" that is different to that?

It's conceptually true because I conceptualized the proof.
It's mathematically true because I wrote the proof.
It is empirically true because the proof is confirmed by a mind-independent machine

Comment: Perhaps you wrote a valid proof in Mathematical logic.  There is a distinction between validity and soundness. You seem to imply Mathematical validity must apply to reality which is blatantly false.                  And no objectivity is not defined as you stated. Objective truth does not require empirical sense data for x to hold a truth value. Now you only apply a true value when you become aware of x. Truth in math & science hold this mistaken view.. objectivity holds truth is not based on personal awareness.  X can be true prior to your awareness.

Comment: OP is spamming this "thesis" all over the internet, for what it's worth.

Comment: @user4894 you don't do your very best to disprove yourself when you come up with an outlandish idea against a "law" that has stood for thousands of years? 

I sure know how ridiculous it sounds. But as any scientist - I must evaluate both hypotheses. I could be wrong - I could be right.

P.S you MAY be exaggerating a little. It's just reddit and stack exchange ;)

Comment: @Logikal then what is your objection. If mathematical proof is sufficient, and empirical proof is not necessary - then I have met a higher bar?

I have ticked the conceptual, computational/mathematical and empirical boxes.

Comment: You are not understanding the proper expression of the LNC. You are reading it as a child would literally put the letters together to find meaning as you did. CONTEXT matters and you are not interpreting the better version of LNC. The LNC expresses that x must have exactly one truth value regardless of you having evidence & also impossible to have more than one truth value that represents x at the same time, place and CONTEXT of x.  If anyone finds an x that has more than exactly one truth value there is a distinction in context, place and time that has been bypassed, omitted or avoided.

Comment: @TypeTheorist Not nice to lie. https://forum.philosophynow.org/viewtopic.php?f=26&t=26183

Comment: @user4894 ah well, that settles it then. The whole internet is 3 websites.

Comment: @Logikal I understand the LNC just fine (P and not P). What you are not getting is that there is difference between theory and practice. Show me the PHYSICAL implementation of that which evaluates the expression - be it a logic circuit, a brain, a CPU or any other contraption.  Whatever that machine IS, it needs to evaluate the LNC in ZERO TIME. BY DEFINITION.  No such machine EXISTS! The LNC is conceptually wrong. And so whatever machine evaluates the LNC has to read P twice. All you need to do is to flip P's value in between the readings.

Comment: In Mathematical logic that might hold. It does not hold in Aristotelian logic. There it is impossible for the same thing to hold a truth value of false and not false at the same time, location & context as I previously stated. You are still reading the logical law as a Mathematical aspect when it was not designed for that. Empirically you can't have A in a literal sense & a not A in the same literal sense.  Your program is conceptual -not literal. Try doing this: make a literally meaningful sentence that is scientifically verifiable  & prove your point. This you can't do without a false claim.

Comment: @TypeTheorist I caught you in a lie. Have a nice life.

Comment: A genuine omission is a lie now? Heh. Life is not going to be fun for you if you are that anal about everything.

Comment: @Logikal pay attention. "impossible for the same thing to hold a truth value of false and not false at the SAME TIME". This is Aristotle's error. He ignored time.
You read left to right, do you not? So you aren't reading (P and not P) AT THE SAME TIME. You are reading the expression 0.05 seconds apart. Just like any physical system would. So in those 0.05 seconds between reading "P" and "not P". I switch its value!

Comment: Well if the time is different the law as philosophy understands it PROVES the current definition in philosophy true as I have repeatedly said x must hold the same value the only one value in the same LOCATION, TIME and CONTEXT.  Here you are expressing TIME is distinct.  Thus your proof does not unhinge the philosophical LNC concept. For you to blow it out of the water you would need a literal and physical object where you can sense verify this PHYSICAL object has more than ONE truth value going on simultaneously in the same location,  same second intervals & contextual meaning of the object

Comment: @Logikal ok, in what universe do philosophers live? One with a pause button?

PRECISELY my point. Now you get it :) In whatver universe the LNC is a "law" - it's not this one.

Comment: No not at all. But now it seems we agree you cant unhinge the LNC because your x can possibly change or indeed changes truth value over time. Another possibility is that at a different time that x is not the same it was 10 years ago because it evolved, matured, adopted to new data, etc. So x may look to you the same but the x is not the same x as before. That is a new x you prove something about and cant honestly apply to the old x without an error made.

Comment: @Logikal you are talking religion now. In this universe there is no such thing as "AT THE SAME TIME", Time does not stop. For anyone! 

To conceptualize the LNC as "P and not P AT THE SAME TIME" is to say "square circle"

Comment: No it doesn't.  Because time changes does not automatically change other attributes in object x. As a matter if fact many attributes of x remain the same. In any event if your understanding were correct then your own premise necessarily implies disproving the LNC is possible. Why because according to you if time changes. . . . That is why you cant literally read the LNC as mathematics.  Mathematics does not fill in those details as I did.

Comment: @Logikal you literally just rejected quantum physics.

Answer (score 8):

No, you did not contradict LNC. In your program `(( A == A ) and (A != A))` is true, but you also changed the function of '==' and '!=' so that '!=' is not longer a negation of '==':

Your '==' function always returns `True`:

```
def __eq__(self, other):
    self.last = True
    return self.last
```

But your '!=' function no longer behaves as the negation of '==':

```
  def __ne__(self, other):
    self.last = not self.last
    return not self.last
```

Since '!=' is no longer a negation of '==', this says absolutely nothing about LNC.

Comment: This was intentional. I decoupled the meaning of "==" and "!=". In doing so I am able to make A behave LIKE a quantum object. Where the LNC is a classical object.

This is precisely my point. LNC exists outside of time. This universe is temporal/quantum.

Comment: You have made the same error as every Aristotelian :)

You have conflated identity and equality!

ID(A) == ID(A)
A != A
A == A

These are THREE distinct operations that can have THREE distinct meaning in English. Paraconsistent logic...

https://repl.it/repls/RoughRegularLead

Comment: What you should infer from the fact that "A == x" evaluates as true is that you need to define what you mean by "==" ;)

Identity is maintained. Equality is not. What does it mean for a Cat to be equal to a Cat ? Are they entangled or what?

Comment: All of your objections have been addressed here: https://repl.it/repls/ActiveImportantDifference

Comment: You changed equality to a different function (which always returns 'true'). Once it's a different function what you say about it does not apply to equality. You're just playing around with symbols.

Comment: you are confusing equality for identity.
The law of identity states that a thing is the same as itself.
There is no law which states that a thing must be equal to itself.

If you think "equality" has some precise, meaningful and objective definition - define it.

Comment: @TypeTheorist Point taken. Equality is not identity. But you're missing my main point: you've shown that "eq(A,A) & ne(A,A)" is true. But ne is not a negation of eq in your definition. So that does not say anything about LNC, since LNC refers to statements of the form "X & ~X".

Comment: so change it? You understand the strategy. In order to evaluate (X & not X) the "observer" needs to sample X twice. That takes non-zero time.

In between the samplings - flip it's value. It's just an oscillator.

Comment: @TypeTheoris You can do whatever you like with X's value. LNC says that *contradictions* aren't true. Once you change X's value in between, it's *no longer a contradiction*. You could have made __eq__ to always return True and __ne__ to always return True, and it would work just the same. Would that show anything? No.

Comment: which is precisely the point. You can't evaluate two propositions (P and not P) at the SAME TIME. Not in this universe.

Comment: @TypeTheorist Well, LNC says that they cannot be true *at the same time*, so if you can't evaluate them at the same time, LNC is still correct.

Comment: nobody and nothing in this universe can evaluate them at the same time.
It may be correct, but only for a universe with a "pause" button.

Answer (score 4):

Sentences, unlike their corresponding propositions, are not abstract entities, and as tokens are composed of matter.

But sentences too can violate the LNC:

```
I am either a toad or a frog because I am neither.
```

And the fact I can utter this sentence does not make any physical law act to violate the LNC.

I am just doing so in my imagination, whereas your program does so in its analysis.

The only important difference I see is that the above reads like nonsense, whereas your computer program actually makes sense: but that's because how it behaves can be made sense of with the LNC. Just as my (confusing) expression might express some unusual, but not physiologically impossible, state of mind.

Interesting project though!

Comment: I don't see a contradiction ;) It's just semantically/grammatically meaningless.

You are getting bogged down in language now. A computer program has a continued effect on the future. After it has been uttered.

A linguistic expression stops after the final punctuation mark.

Comment: i get what you mean... that your program actually does violate the LNC rather than merely appear to. but, even supposing that people only seem to imagine violating the LNC, i don't think your software physically does, only in some abstract sense... real types?

Comment: In a paradigm of constructive mathematics anything that can be constructed (read: defined) is real.

You are in the Matrix!  If the LNC is defined it exists. And because contradictions don't exist it contradicts itself out of existence.

Comment: i am sad that my answer was downvoted, i don't see what's wrong with it... i guess cos it was thought to be badly written?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you would understand @Logikal comments if you think about it like this: A physical machine (computer) takes a set of input conditions, then evaluates/operate according to a *predetermined* logic to produce a new set, then repeat... Time is intrinsic to the operation. (Your program works by exploiting the time aspect.)
However *formal* logic has no time operation. When a logical proof is done with "pen and paper" it is not "operation", as above, from one step to the the next. Rather it is *discovery* of the next step, a **revealing** of something that must of been there all along... "x" don't change on paper, everywhere it is used x has the same identity, *and the same value*. In a computer program x is a variable, it can change between clock cycles; in Formal logic x is a statement, a different x is a *different* statement.

So what the question now becomes is: **Does Logic actually apply to physical reality?** Answer is: "Yes, *within a specified domain*." The existence of your computer itself is proof of that. Did you disprove LNC? No, not the LNC of Logic. What *did* you prove? That logical formalism *plus* time has a slightly larger domain of application than logic alone... Sure. That Reality cannot be fully described with a consistent logical system... Maybe. (And maybe you have the beginnings of a refutation of Tegmark's mathematical universe.)

Comment: I think using computers to justify the LNC is a bad example. Computers are temporal phenomena... Clocks, timing and synchronicity are fundamental to their correct functioning.

It is precisely because they are temporal is why I was able to do what I did.

If they were static (like pen and paper) I can't produce this result.

Comment: Important to remember it is not the static nature that prevents the result, rather it is the nature of Logic itself. Computer logic is also static, but only for that moment of evaluation at the end of a clock cycle. The temporal aspect of a computer _program_ allows you to add something... An external and stronger Logic can check the completeness of a weaker one, similarly an external rationality (you) in conjunction with the computer's (physical) logic can produce results not possible for the physical alone. Note, there is work on temporal logics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temporal_logic

Comment: The Aristotelian universe is so far removed from the Temporal one it's uncanny. If a contradiction means (p and not p) at "the same time" the shortest possible time-interval is experienced at the scale of a Planck length.

Comment: If I draw the truth table for an "and gate", and you draw the truth table for an "and gate": Did we draw _different_ tables, more to the point did we use different logic? If you have an "and gate" and give it inputs, then at a later time give it the same inputs: Did the _logic_ change? - _We_ are far removed from the Aristotelian universe, today it's best to think of Logic as a non-temporal abstraction (handy as it is). There are also some pertinent subtleties, concerning eg. simultaneity, that remain in debate. - also see: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/53745/33787 and

Comment: immaterial. If your AND-gate is supposed to return 1 for "1 and 1" but I manage to make it return 0. I have control over it.

Input validation problem. Implementation vulnerability.

Comment: But then it wouldn't _be_ an AND-gate would it? Regardless, it is your interference that makes it misbehave not a fault in the logic...As mentioned, a logical system has a defined domain, the real world is a far larger domain: If you add something to Logic in order to "have control", then you don't have the logic to which LNC is applicable anymore.

Comment: potato potatoh. I have control over ALL deduction systems by virtue of input validation. Garbage in - Garbage out. What good is  "logic" then if I can make it say whatever I want? It's just LEGO for your mind....

Comment: @TypeTheorist No! NOT "potato potatoh". If you have Logic A and you add ANYTHING to it, then you have Logic B. If you haven't proven the consistency of Logic B, by means of a more powerfull Logic C, then it is UNSURPRISING if you find contradictions in Logic B.

Comment: @TypeTheorist 
Of course GIGO! Any computer professional will confirm. But validation is done BEFORE Logic is invoked, NOT during. Logic work BY DEFINITION, instantaneously. Whatever control you try to exert, changes the defined Logic.

Comment: @TypeTheorist 
Think about what you are looking at, look at what you are holding, none of it would be possible without Logic. None of it embodies the entirety of reality. Logic is a TOOL, it is USED by a mind. The fact that you can break it doesn't mean it is faulty, it means you have used it wrong. Essentially you have read the packaging of a hammer which said: "Cannot be used for screws.", and then you went and used the hammer to beat in a screw...

Comment: @TypeTheorist NOTE: I'm saying you used Logic ineffectively, NOT "programming". Actually you used programming quite effectively...

Comment: ok, what is the "effective way" to use logic?
Any sofware engineer or an information security expert will tell you that input validation is done IN logic.

Comment: @TypeTheorist Computer languages use logic effectively. None of those people use logic, they use computers. If the logic in peoples heads were the same as the one on paper, then nobody would make mistakes while doing math or logic exercises. LNC only applies to _consistent_ logics, but there are many others... You display a fundamental misconception about the differences in _layers_ and applications of Logics, and the even more fundamental aspect of how they are constrained _by definition_.

Comment: @TypeTheorist The previous comment contain some "mistakes" which you will only see once you understand why computers are like onions.

Answer (score 3):

I feel there is much misunderstanding here. In order for the LNC to be properly applied to a contradictory-pair of statements one member of the pair must be true and the other must be false. This is a rule. If we don't know that one is true and the other false then we cannot apply the LNC.

This is Aristotle's rule for contradictory pairs. It is remarkable, crazy even, how often it is ignored by philosophers. Where we ignore we reduce the dialectic to rubble and cease to think reasonably.

There is no known example of nature breaking the LNC and there never will be. It is defined so as to be foolproof. Where it is broken it does not apply. Aristotle was no slouch. If the LNC does not apply to pair of propositions then it should not be applied. The definition is a completely secure tautology.

Comment: The problem I am pointing out is conceptual. (p and not p) cannot be true at the SAME TIME.

And in the vagueness of "same time" I have merely exploited the definition.
The concept of "same time" can only be defined as a bounded interval. It requires duration whereas the LNC is "timeless".

And so two things can be true and false in very rapid succession. It's called an oscillator. 

And given an oscillator the following is true: P and not-P and P and not-P and P and not-P and P...

Time waits for nobody. Not even Aristotle.

Comment: Fundamentally what I am exploiting is a concept that any computer scientist understands as "atomicity".  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atomicity_(database_systems) we can't do it without "pausing" the universe e.g locking.

Comment: @TypeTheorist - I struggle to see the relevance of time. I'd agree with Christo's answer and say that that time has no role in dialectic logic.

Comment: then your logic does not describe this universe.

Comment: @TypeTheorist - I find your view difficult to understand. A and not-A cannot both be true (or false) at the same time or at different times. This is what 'A' and 'not-A' mean.

Comment: what time-interval do you have in mind when you say "at the same time"? 1 second ? 1 millisecond? 1 microsecond? 1 nanosecond? 1 picosecond? A quantum wave particle apparently can be both here and there at the same time...

Comment: @TypeTheorist - If a quanta can be here and there at the same time or different times the LNC is unaffected. It is not time dependent. For your argument you would need to find a case of A/not-A where both are true or both false, and yet by definition this would not be a case of A/not-A.

Comment: that is a conceptual error. NOTHING is time-independent in this universe!
My OP literally contains example code where (A = A) and (A != A) are both true.

Comment: @TypeTheorist By what _Theory of truth_ do you claim that "Logic is time dependent"? - Wikipedia articles linked in this summery has better explanations: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/q/59490/33787

Comment: @TypeTheorist - If you can find an example of a true contradiction you will become famous.

Comment: @christo183 by the pertinently obvious fact that we live in a temporal universe. And that physics has not solved T-Symmetry. Any phenomenon (even logic) that "exists outside of time" is a conceptual error.

Comment: @TypeTheorist No! There is no such thing as "Time" (Einstein/Gödel)! "Time" is a simplification, a shorthand way of communicating some aspect of experience/reality. And no, "pertinently obvious" is not a _theory of thruth_.

Comment: @TypeTheorist - (Part 7: MENTORS Kurt Gödel): rudyrucker.com/transrealbooks/collectedessays/#_Toc53

Comment: @christo183 I am sorry. All of physics disagrees with you. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Problem_of_time

Comment: @christo183 if there is no such thing as time, then please change the number 4 at the end of this comment to a 5.

Change this to a 5 ----> 4.